# Objective-C, ownership and class methods

Tags: objective-c, release, ownership, class-method

First off, I'm a Objective-C newbie. :)

I've learned that anything that starts with `alloc`, `new`, and `copy`, gives the caller ownership of the returned object. Does this also apply to class methods? I'm guessing it *does*, and a recent crash in one of my unit tests seems to confirm it. Apple's Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide doesn't say anything whether there's a difference between class and instance methods.

**Update**
What I mean that it also applies to class methods is really the "inverse". For instance, NSDecimalNumber has a class method called `+decimalNumberWithDecimal:`. It seems to return an auto released object (if I release it explicitly, a crash occurs shortly after that). In hindsight, the answer to my question is obvious, as Apple's guide refers to `new` and `alloc` as ownership-giving methods, and they're all class methods. Sorry for taking up your valuable time. :)

Comment: Do you mean a class method which generates an object for you?
Yes of course. This pattern is one key of the memory management in obj-c. Even non apple framework apply to this pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Yes this applies to class methods since `alloc` and `new` are class methods which return ownership to the caller. The prefix of `copy` or `mutableCopy` should be used for instance methods returning ownership.

**Edit For The Update:**

You are correct a method like `+decimalNumberWithDecimal:` is expected to return an autoreleased object, therefore there is no reason to release it. If however they decided to name the method `+newNumberWithDecimal:` then you would have ownership of the returned object and need to release it. Clang static analyzer will actually complain if you prefix a method with `new` and return an autoreleased object.

Comment: @JeffWolski: Apple's programming guides explicitly mention `copy` (and variations) as methods that give ownership. See here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html

Answer (score 3):

Also `alloc` and `release`.  `init` does not indicate ownership, you are likely mixing that up with `alloc`.  You can memorise it easily with the mnemonic *NARC*.

If you are naming any class methods `init`, `copy` or `retain`, you should stop that.  Those are methods that only make sense in the context of instances.  `alloc` and `new` are class methods and should only be used in that context.  Don't name instance methods `alloc` or `new`.

The reason why the guide doesn't say that it applies to both instance methods and class methods is that the methods in question are clearly a mixture of both, so it's obviously the case.

Comment: Yes, I mixed init up with new! :)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, this is almost correct.  `alloc`, `new`, and `copy` give you ownership of the returned object.  These are class methods.  Other class methods should return an autoreleased object.  Instance methods should also return an autoreleased object.

`init` does not effect ownership and should be use in conjunction with `alloc` as follows.

```
[[SomeCoolClass alloc] init]
```

`new` is usually the same thing as the above and is sometimes described as "almost deprecated" because it is a throwback to the NeXT days when the allocation and initialization were done in the same step and could not be plot apart as we do today with `alloc` and `init`.

Release does not effect ownership, but should only be used on object you already own. Otherwise a crash is likely to occur.

Retain also does not affect ownership, but should only be used on an object you already own.  Otherwise the object may not be deallocated when it should be.  The result could be a crash, but it can also be very very strange behavior that is difficult to troubleshoot because messages may be sent to the original object that was supposed to have been deallocated instead of a new object pointed to at the same address.